# SQL formatting issue in python

Tags: python, mysql, sql

For the below query from python/ mysql

```
op = dbcon.query("select * from configtable where xmlfile like '%"Check_This_Attribute" enabled="true"%'")
```

getting error:

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

can anyone plz assist

Comment: What's the query that you want to run, just in plain sql? It's hard to tell which double quotes are wrong because you've messed up the syntax and which ones are wrong because of unhandled escapes.

Answer (score 0):

If Check_This_Attribute is a python variable, then you need to concatenate the string with a + sign, and escape your double-quotes.

```
"select * from configtable where xmlfile like '%" + Check_This_Attribute + "%enabled=\"true\"%'"
```

Comment: not a python variable its a way to access config xml

Comment: Store your SQL command in a string. 
`sql = 'put your string here'`
Then do some print() statements to see what it looks like and do trial and error until you get it.

Answer (score 0):

You have double quotes inside your string that is delimited by double quotes. That can't work. Try escaping them:

```
op = dbcon.query("select * from configtable where xmlfile like '%\"Check_This_Attribute\" enabled=\"true\"%'")
```

In case `Check_This_Attribute` is not a string but a variable, use e.g. a format string to insert its contents:

```
op = dbcon.query(f"select * from configtable where xmlfile like '%\"{Check_This_Attribute}\" enabled=\"true\"%'")
```